# Installing printer+scanner dell V105 on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: printing, dell, scanner, lexmark

I recently got an old dell V105 printer and wanted to install it on ubuntu, however it could not find specific drivers and with the generic drivers ubuntu proposed, I cannot scan any documents. So, are there any other drivers (f.i. a similar printer from other mark eg lexmark) which I could use for full operation?

Answer (score 0):

OpenPrinting classes the v105's big brother, [the v305, as a "Paperweight"](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Dell/Dell-V305). There's extremely little to no chance you'll ever get the printer to do anything useful from a pure Ubuntu environment.

I'm sorry to say that Dell are famously unsupportive of their printers on Linux and in this case there isn't even a driver for OSX.

If you *really* need it to work, you'd probably be able to use VirtualBox to run a copy of XP and pass the printer through to it... But it'll be slow and buggy. Given the price of printers, it's almost certainly cheaper (in time) to buy a new, Linux supported printer.